# Extraction of String Array from Object made up of different Object

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I'am new at java. This may be a silly question for many of you.
But I'am Struck so please help. There is something that I'am trying to make. I'am using these two below classes. I'am defining the java codes here.

public class People {

```
private int id, id100px;
private String rollNumber;
private String mobile_number, email_id, nick_name, hobbies, dob, name;
private Testimony[] testimony;


    public People(String name, int id, String mobile_number, String email_id,  Testimony ... testimony) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.mobile_number = mobile_number;
        this.email_id = email_id;
        this.testimony = testimony;
    }

    public Testimony[] getTestimony() {
        return testimony;
    }

    public String getEmail_id() {
        return email_id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getMobile_number() {
        return mobile_number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Testimony {
    private String testimony;
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Testimony(String testimony,String name, int id){
        this.testimony = testimony;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String gettestimony() {
        return testimony;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getid() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Now, I need to extract every data for every entry in People Class. I'am using getMethods for everything.
I'am having trouble with extraction of data for the Testimony Object, I need to extract and save String testimony[] of Testimony class for only one specific object or People Class

Answer (score -1):

Since Testimony is a var arg in the constructor `Testimony ... testimony`

you have to define a getter like:

```
public Testimony[] getTestimony()(
}
```

for the setter can apply the same logic:

```
public void setTestimony(Testimony[] testimony){
    this.Testimony = testimony;
}
```

---

## Update:

if you need the info in every Testimony you can define a method for printing those:

```
public void printAllTestimonies(){
for (Testimony testim : testimony) {
            System.out.println("Testimony: "+ testim.gettestimony());
            System.out.println("Name: "+ testim.getname());
            System.out.println("Id: "+ testim.getid());
        } 
}
```